# General twisted cubics

Tags: algebraic-geometry, intersection-theory, moduli-space

In Joe Harris's text book entitled : Algebraic geometry, a first course, page : $ 55 $, we find the following paragraph which i don't really understand :

> ... As another example, consider again twisted cubics. Any twisted
>   cubic : $ C $ can be written as the image of the map of the form : $$
>  t \to [ a_{03} t^3 + a_{02} t^2 + a_{01} t + a_{00} , \dots , a_{33}
>  t^3 + a_{32} t^2 + a_{31} t + a_{30} ] $$  where the determinant of
>   the matrix $ (a_{ij} ) $ of coefficients is nonzero, so that we can
>   describe $ C $ by specifying a non singular $ 4 \times 4 $ matrix. Of
>   course, this does not give a bijection between the variety $ U \subset
>  (K)^{16} $ of invertible $ 4 \times 4 $ matrices and the set of
>   twisted cubics, since the curve $ C $ does not determine this
>   expression.
>
> Alternately, recall from theorem $ 1.18 $ that any twisted cubic is
>   determined by six points in general position  in $ \mathbb{P}^3 $.
>   Thus, we get a twisted cubic for any point in the open subset $ V
>  \subset ( \mathbb{P}^3 )^6 $ corresponding to configurations in
>   general position, though as in the previous case, this is not a
>   bijection.

Could you explain to me please, in onother simpler way why there is no bijection between the variety $ U \subset (K)^{16} $ of invertible $ 4 \times 4 $ matrices and the set of twisted cubics ? It's not quite clear for me this small text above.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The text does not say that there is no bijection (there are for instance when $K=\Bbb R$ or $\Bbb C$, since both sets are continuously infinite), but that *the map described here* does not provide a bijection.

The reason why the present map does not give a bijection is that you can multiply all terms $a_{i,j}$ by a fixed non-zero element of $K$, this will give you another matrix but will describe the same twisted cubic.

Comment: Thank you very much Arnaud Mortier. It's clear now.  :)

Comment: @YoYo you're very welcome :)